# GPU Memory in TensorFlow container with NVIDIA SLI

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I have constructed a machine-learning computer with two RTX 2070 SUPER NVIDIA GPUs connected with SLI Bridge, Windows OS (SLI verified in NVIDIA Control Panel).

I have benchmarked the system using http://ai-benchmark.com/alpha and got impressive results.

In order to take the best advantage of libraries that use the GPU for scientific tasks (cuDF) I have created a TensorFlow Linux container:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

using “latest-gpu-py3-jupyter” tag.

I have then connected PyCharm to this container and configured its interpreter as an interpreter of the same project (I mounted the host project folder in the container).

When I run the same benchmark on the container, I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[50,56,56,144] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[node MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_2/depthwise/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ai_benchmark/utils.py:238) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

This error relates to the exhaustion of GPU memory inside the container.

Why is the GPU on the windows host successfully handle the computation and the GPU on the Linux container exhaust the memory?

What makes this difference? is that related to memory allocation in the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an awesome link from docker.com that explains why your desired workflow won't work.](https://forums.docker.com/t/gpu-access-from-docker-ubuntu-container-on-top-of-windows-10-pro/71534)  It also wouldn't work with RAPIDS cudf either.  Docker Desktop works using Hyper V which isolates the hardware and doesn't access to the GPU the way the Linux drivers expect. Also, nvidia-docker is linux only

I can let you know that RAPIDS (cudf) currently doesn't support this implementation either. Windows, however, does work better with a Linux host.  For both tensorflow and cudf, I strongly recommend that you use (or dual boot) one of the recommended OSes as your host OS, found here: https://rapids.ai/start.html#prerequisites.  If you need Windows in your workflow, you can run it on top of your Linux host.

There is a chance that in the future, a WSL version will allow you to run RAPIDS on Windows, letting you- on your own- craft an on Windows solution.

Hope this helps!